# IE9 keeps telling me that "Your security setting level puts your computer at risk"

Tags: internet-explorer-9, security-warning

So, the other day, after at least two years of being annoyed by the question that Windows gives when I try to run a program that I downloaded, which asks me if I'm sure I want to run it; I searched IE options for anything that would disable that question.

After a long time searching, I finally came upon one security setting which enable me to suppress the question. I disable it and browsed the web happily using Chrome (my main browser) for about two days, when I needed to open IE in order to access a website that was designed for Microsoft browsers. That's when I came upon another, much more bothering, message:

[image: Security at Risk]

The worst part is that the message doesn't disappear after browsing to a site or anything. Anyone knows what I could do? Besides, of course, restoring the setting?

Comment: Google Chrome Frame is awesome as it installs like a browser plugin, in to IE.. Using that, you can then use IE, or so you think, except everything's actually driven by Chrome - which you know, is good.

Answer (score 11):

Open **Group Policy** (type **gpedit.msc** in the *Search programs and files* field).  Go to

> Computer Configuration | Administrative Templates | Windows Components | Internet Explorer

Look for **Turn off the Security Settings Check feature** and set it to **Enabled**.

[image]

Comment: This answer makes me happy. I can't wait to do this at home.

Comment: It looks like the right way, but for some reason it didn't worked here. Sure it works for IE9? One more thing: this has a !@#* side effect: Windows Live Mail stops synchronizing e-mail for some reason. I'll investigate it further this afternoon.

Answer (score 3):

[This site](http://www.geekstogo.com/forum/topic/138460-annoying-ie7-problem/page__view__findpost__p__1359090) suggests you can set `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Security\DisableSecuritySettingsCheck` (DWORD) to 0x1 to kill the error message.

The main problem with downloading and running executables with IE is that the download dialog can be tricked into making you believe the file is not an application, but a document (for example by using Unicode characters in the name that change the writing direction so that cod.exe is shown as exe.doc) - especially since you can change the icon of exe files easily. So, the extra prompt for applications does make sense (you can also configure the same prompt for network or removable drives). If you are sure, you can of course disable it. Or use another browser that ignores unicode direction change characters in names that consist only of ASCII letters (where it is useless, unless in some languages like Arabic or Hebrew).

Comment: For me, `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\POLICIES\MICROSOFT\Internet Explorer\Security\DisableSecuritySettingsCheck` set to 0x1 worked, but I had to actually add the `Internet Explorer\Security\DisableSecuritySettingsCheck` portion (those keys were not already present).

Answer (score 1):

The method described by Nicu Zecheru does work with IE9 in order to get rid of the "Security Risk" banner, however you must reboot for the new policy to take effect. Once rebooted open your IE9 Browser and open the a web page. The only warning that will come up is "Press here if you do not want to see the warning again", close the browser again and reopen and no warning banners will appear after.